# Is there a way in ruby 1.9 to remove invalid byte sequences from strings?

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, ruby-1.9, utf

Suppose you have a string like `"€foo\xA0"`, encoded UTF-8, Is there a way to remove invalid byte sequences from this string? ( so you get `"€foo"` )

In ruby-1.8 you could use `Iconv.iconv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', "€foo\xA0")` but that is now deprecated. `"€foo\xA0".encode('UTF-8')` doesn't do anything, since it is already UTF-8. I tried:

```
"€foo\xA0".force_encoding('BINARY').encode('UTF-8', :undef => :replace, :replace => '')
```

which yields

`"foo"`

But that also loses the valid multibyte character €

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147449/delete-non-utf-characters-from-a-string-in-ruby/12149403#comment133367536_12149403 for some more newer 2.1+ options.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
"€foo\xA0".chars.select(&:valid_encoding?).join
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the `\xF1` in this string `"eEspa\xF1a;FB"`

Comment: @Dorian, on 1.9.3 IRB console, `"eEspa\xF1a;FB".chars.select{|i| i.valid_encoding?}.join` returns `"eEspaa;FB" ` ...do you not get that behavior or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 35):

```
"€foo\xA0".encode('UTF-16le', invalid: :replace, replace: '').encode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: I was under the impression it has a larger character set than UTF-8, meaning you don't loose any valid data. Unfortunately the following doesn't work:

`"€foo\xA0".encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '')`

because the string is already UTF-8, so it will not be encoded again.

Comment: FWIW, running a test on a large file I found this method to be an order of magnitude faster than the `valid_encoding` approach.

Comment: UTF-8 and UTF-16 can both represent all Unicode characters. The only difference is the way the characters are encoded.

Comment: `UTF-32` is also an option, but `UTF-16` seems to work well enough. The new [emoji characters](http://www.grumdrig.com/emoji-list/) might need the extra space.

Comment: All UTF encodings are equally capable of encoding all possible Unicode characters; there's no difference in that regard between UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32. The only practical difference is the [output size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings#Eight-bit_environments).

Comment: Throws an error with this string: `"eEspa\xF1a;FB"`

Comment: @Dorian: what Ruby version?

Comment: @VanderHoorn: it was ruby < 2.1 because it works with ruby 2.1+

Comment: @Dorian: I see. Could it be a Ruby 2.0.x issue? Because I think I used Ruby 1.9.3 when I answered the original question.

Comment: With ruby 2.1 encoding from "the same encoding to the same encoding" it no longer a no-op FWIW so doing the double encoding trick hopefully is no longer necessary?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 2.0 and 1.9.3

```
"€foo\xA0".encode(Encoding::UTF_8, Encoding::UTF_8, :invalid => :replace)
```

Ruby 2.1+

```
"€foo\xA0".scrub
```

These replace the `\xA0` with a � symbol by default, you can specify a different replacement parameter.

Answer (score -2):

```
    data = '' if not (data.force_encoding("UTF-8").valid_encoding?)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Severin how come not? It looks like an (incorrect) answer to the question. It removes all invalid byte sequence from a string. It just removes all valid ones as well.