# How to change deprecated iconv to String#encode for invalid UTF8 correction

Tags: ruby, unicode, character-encoding, iconv

I get sources from the web and sometimes the encoding of the material is not 100% UTF8 byte sequence valid. I use iconv to silently ignore these sequences to get a cleaned string.

```
@iconv = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
valid_string = @iconv.iconv(untrusted_string)
```

However now the iconv has been deprecated, I see its deprecation warning a lot.

**iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode**

I tried the converting it, using `String#encode`'s `:invalid` and `:replace` options, but it seems not to be working (i.e. the incorrect byte sequence has not been removed). What is the correct way to use String#encode for this?

Comment: I think what you're trying is very dangerous. Text encoding is like pregnancy: either you have UTF8 or you don't. You can't just have a "bit" of UTF8. If there's an error, you *have* to abort. Otherwise your converter may be susceptible to attacks with maliciously prepared strings.

Comment: I am writing a crawler and there will be a page out there being a bit invalid. So cleaning the bytes is all I can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question that Martijn linked to has what seem to be the two best ways to do that, but Martijn made an understandable but incorrect change when copying the second approach to his answer here.  Doing .encode('UTF-8', <options>).encode('UTF-8') doesn't work.  As indicated in the original answer in the other question, the key is to encode to a *different* encoding, then back to UTF-8.  If your original string is already flagged as UTF-8 in ruby's internals then ruby will ignore any call to encode it as UTF-8.

In the following examples I'm going to use "a#{0xFF.chr}b".force_encoding('UTF-8') to produce a string that ruby believes is UTF-8 but which contains invalid UTF-8 bytes.

```
1.9.3p194 :019 > "a#{0xFF.chr}b".force_encoding('UTF-8')
 => "a\xFFb" 
1.9.3p194 :020 > "#{0xFF.chr}".force_encoding('UTF-8').encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Note how encoding to UTF-8 does nothing:

```
1.9.3p194 :016 > "a#{0xFF.chr}b".force_encoding('UTF-8').encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '').encode('UTF-8')
 => "a\xFFb"
```

But encoding to something else (UTF-16) and then back to UTF-8 cleans up the string:

```
1.9.3p194 :017 > "a#{0xFF.chr}b".force_encoding('UTF-8').encode('UTF-16', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '').encode('UTF-8')
 => "ab"
```

Comment: Actually you are right. If I just use UTF-8 throughout, using gsub on the string will still raise "invalid encoding" error. But your answer fixes it. I must have done a lousy testing earlier.

Answer (score 7):

This has been answered in this question:

[Is there a way in ruby 1.9 to remove invalid byte sequences from strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710444/is-there-a-way-in-ruby-1-9-to-remove-invalid-byte-sequences-from-strings)

Use either

```
untrusted_string.chars.select{|i| i.valid_encoding?}.join
```

or

```
untrusted_string.encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '').encode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: the answer says change encoding or encode doesn't do anything. So when writing `wtf.encode('UTF-8', blah blah).encode('UTF-8')`, first encode has no effect here.