# gsub :: ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)

Tags: ruby, utf-8

This code uses the `Hpricot` gem to get HTML that contains UTF-8 characters.

```
# <div>This is a test<a href="">测试</a></div>
div[0].to_html.gsub(/test/, "")
```

When that is run, it spits out this error (pointing at gsub):

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)
```

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure they're utf-8 in the source? What do the actual bytes look like?

Comment: Yes, or else it wouldn't be saying "UTF-8". Here is what it actually checks: `test...<a href="..." target="_top"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Café</a> testing`.

Comment: `.to_html.gsub` with values you specified, it works.Could you give us more details ?

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk: the error message suggests that what you're passing in isn't, in fact, valid UTF-8. This probably means the characters are in another encoding.

Comment: @wooble Yes, I know that. My question is how can I make it valid?

Comment: Find out what encoding it's *really* using, then convert it from that to something you can use.

Comment: @Wooble It's easy to say that but doing it is another story. `"test".encoding #=> UTF-8` and `"test".force_encoding("UTF-8")`. But that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Hpricot's `to_html` calls methods that trigger the error so to get rid of that we need to make the Hpricot document encoding UTF-8, not just that one string. We do that like this:

```
ic = Iconv.new("UTF-8//IGNORE", "UTF-8")
doc = open("http://example.com") {|f| Hpricot(ic.iconv(f.read)) }
```

And then we can call other Hpricot methods but now the whole document has UTF-8 encoding and it won't give us any errors.

Comment: This works fine but deprecated since Ruby 1.9.3. Can you suggest solution via String built-in encodings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710444/is-there-a-way-in-ruby-1-9-to-remove-invalid-byte-sequences-from-strings

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016328/hpricot-utf-8-issues

Answer (score 0):

The to_html looks to return a non-utf8 string in this case.

I had same problem with file containing some non-utf8 characters. The fix I found is not really beautiful, but it could also works for your case :

```
the_utf8_string = the_non_utf8_string.unpack('C*').pack('U*')
```

Be careful, I'm not sure there is no one data lost.

Comment: The unpack+pack I've seen elsewhere was used to "latinize" (remove apostrophes etc) which means data is lost. If the solution above is the same, then it won't be useful here.