# Hpricot - UTF-8 issues

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, hpricot

I get the following error when running the code below:

```
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

The code:

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

doc = open('http://www.amazon.co.jp/') {|f| Hpricot(f.read) }
puts doc.to_html
```

Hpricot cannot parse the Japanese content. Any suggestions on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site doesn't seem to be using UTF-8: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" />`.

Try this instead:

```
open('http://www.amazon.co.jp/') {|f| Hpricot(f.read.encode("UTF-8")) }
```

Comment: Very nice! Fixed the problem. Thank you.