# Delete non-UTF characters from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

How do I delete non-UTF8 characters from a ruby string? I have a string that has for example "xC2" in it. I want to remove that char from the string so that it becomes a valid UTF8.

This:

```
text = x = "foo\xC2bar"
text.gsub!(/\xC2/, '')
```

returns an error:

```
incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```

I was looking at text.unpack('U*') and string.pack as well, but did not get anywhere.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375342/stringencode-not-fixing-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-error/ useful

Answer (score 120):

You can use encode for that.
`text.encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)`

Or `text.scrub`

For more info look into [Ruby-Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode), replaces it by default with a question mark box.

Comment: Every time you see that you got 10 points from this answer you must know how much head banging against a desk you've just saved someone.

Comment: Yup. Here, 10 more points for you.

Answer (score 11):

You could do it like this

```
# encoding: utf-8

class String
  def validate_encoding
    chars.select(&:valid_encoding?).join 
  end
end

puts "testing\xC2 a non UTF-8 string".validate_encoding
#=>testing a non UTF-8 string
```

Comment: `.select(&:valid_encoding?)` instead of `.collect{}` is a lot shorter.

Comment: you'r right ephemient and it stays comprehensible, thanks, i adapt my answer

Comment: This actually works, unlike the most voted answer.

Answer (score 7):

You text have ASCII-8BIT encoding, instead you should use this:

```
String.delete!("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}");
```

It will serve the same purpose.

Comment: I ended up using mystring.delete() since delete! returns nil if the string was not modified, see https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/delete%21

Comment: Removes characters with diacriticals and stuff like that, but works :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `/n`, as in

```
text.gsub!(/\xC2/n, '')
```

to force the Regexp to operate on bytes.

Are you sure this is what you want, though?  Any Unicode character in the range [U+80, U+BF] will have a `\xC2` in its UTF-8 encoded form.

Comment: This gives me `incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)`

Answer (score 4):

Try Iconv

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'iconv'
# => true 
1.9.3p194 :002 > string = "testing\xC2 a non UTF-8 string"
# => "testing\xC2 a non UTF-8 string" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
# => #<Iconv:0x000000026c9290> 
1.9.3p194 :004 > ic.iconv string
# => "testing a non UTF-8 string"
```

Comment: one note: `Iconv` is (will be) deprecated from Rails 3.2 in favour of `String#encode`

Comment: Appears Iconv was deprecated in ruby 1.9 FWIW...guess it's just a gem now for 2.x

Answer (score 3):

The best solution to this problem that I've found is this answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8711118/363293.

In short: `"€foo\xA0".chars.select(&:valid_encoding?).join`

Answer (score -2):

```
data = '' if not (data.force_encoding("UTF-8").valid_encoding?)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually repair a string?