# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby

I use https://github.com/ging/linkser to load url :

```
1.9.3p374 :001 > require 'linkser'
 => true 
1.9.3p374 :002 > l = Linkser.parse 'http://sports.163.com/nba/'
 => #<Linkser::Objects::HTML:0x007f92019e99c8 @url="http://sports.163.com/nba/", @last_url="http://sports.163.com/nba/", @head=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @options={}> 
1.9.3p374 :003 > l.title
encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xC4 0x4E 0x42 0x41
 => "NBA,NBAֱҥ,\xD7钭ㄒ档"
```

Is it possible to convert the byte sequence to correct utf8 string ?

Comment: this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147449/delete-non-utf-characters-from-a-string-in-ruby/12149403#12149403

Answer (score 0):

The actual encoding of the page is GBK, aka gb2312. A quick glance at [linkser source](https://github.com/ging/linkser/tree/master/lib) shows no handling of encodings, so it is left to Net::HTTP, which has a [long standing bug about that](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2567), targeted for Ruby 2.0.0.